# How to extract and verify PDF signature (PKCS7) with openssl?

Tags: php, bash, pdf, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I would like to detect signed PDFs in PHP and verify if the signature is valid. From this [document](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf) I have written this PHP code below.

What it does is:

1. Extract the PKCS7 code (it works because I can get the details from Openssl)
2. Compute the SHA256 hash of the document.

At the end I has a PKCS7 file and a SHA256.

Now, I would like to verify my signature against my PKCS7 file. How can I do this? I initially looked to the `digest_enc_alg`/`sha256WithRSAEncryption`/`enc_digest`, but it seems it is not what I am looking about.

```
class VerifyPDF
{
    public static function getByteRange($filename)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        if (!preg_match_all('/ByteRange\[\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*\]/',
            $content, $matches))
        {
            throw new \Exception('Unable to get certificate');
        }

        return [
            intval($matches[1][0]), // Offset of the first part (usually 0)
            intval($matches[2][0]), // Size of the first part
            intval($matches[3][0]), // Offset to the second part
            intval($matches[4][0])  // Size of the second part
        ];
    }

    public static function get_pkcs7($filename)
    {
        [$o1, $l1, $o2, $l2] = self::getByteRange($filename);

        if (!$fp = fopen($filename, 'rb')) {
            throw new \Exception("Unable to open $filename");
        }

        $signature = stream_get_contents($fp, $o2 - $l1 - 2, $l1 + 1);
        fclose($fp);

        file_put_contents('out.pkcs7', hex2bin($signature));
    }

    public static function compute_hash($filename)
    {
        [$o1, $l1, $o2, $l2] = self::getByteRange($filename);

        if (!$fp = fopen($filename, 'rb')) {
            throw new \Exception("Unable to open $filename");
        }

        $i = stream_get_contents($fp, $l1, $o1);
        $j = stream_get_contents($fp, $l2, $o2);

        if (strlen($i) != $l1 || strlen($j) != $l2) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid chunks');
        }

        fclose($fp);

        return hash('sha256', $i . $j);
    }
}
```

The HASH I get is:

```
5036ae43aba11ce626f6f9b1d5246ba0700e217655b9ff927e31fbefadfa2182
```

So inspired from [this](http://qistoph.blogspot.com/2012/01/manual-verify-pkcs7-signed-data-with.html) I did the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
PKCS7='out.pkcs7'

# Extract Digest (SHA256)
OFFSET=$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $PKCS7 | \
    perl -ne 'print $1 + $2 if /(\d+):d=\d\s+hl=(\d).*?256 prim.*HEX DUMP/m')
dd if=$PKCS7 of=signed-sha256.bin bs=1 skip=$OFFSET count=256

# Extract Public key 
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -inform der -in $PKCS7 | \
    tac | sed '/-----BEGIN/q' | tac > client.pem
openssl x509 -in client.pem -pubkey -noout > client.pub.pem

# Verify the signature
openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey client.pub.pem < signed-sha256.bin > verified.bin

# Get Hash and compare with the computed hash from the PDF
openssl asn1parse -inform der -in verified.bin | grep -Po '\[HEX DUMP\]:\K\w+$' | tr A-F a-f
```

Which gives me this:

```
C8581962753927BB57B66B1D0D0F4B33A29EF3E03DA12D2329DB72763AC7EDB6
```

So unfortunately by two hashes do not match...

Am I missing something?

Comment: You completely ignore the **Subfilter** entry of your signature. Depending on the subfilter value the format of the signature container and the actually signed data do differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [blog](http://qistoph.blogspot.com/2012/01/manual-verify-pkcs7-signed-data-with.html) you were *inspired from* shows the following graphics to explain the PKCS#7 signature container structure

[image: screen shot]

Actually, though, this represents only the most simple structure defined by PKCS#7. If you look at the `SignerInfo` specification (`content - signerInfos - SignerInfo`), you'll see

```
   SignerInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
     version Version,
     issuerAndSerialNumber IssuerAndSerialNumber,
     digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
     authenticatedAttributes
       [0] IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL,
     digestEncryptionAlgorithm
       DigestEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier,
     encryptedDigest EncryptedDigest,
     unauthenticatedAttributes
       [1] IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }
```

*([RFC 2315 section 9.2 "SignerInfo type"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#section-9.2))*

In particular there are the OPTIONAL `authenticatedAttributes` which you don't find in the sketch above. But in any current signature profile to be taken seriously these `authenticatedAttributes` (aka signed attributes) are actually required!

Furthermore, if there are `authenticatedAttributes` in a PKCS#7 signature container signer info object, the encrypted digest is *not* the digest of the document data but instead the digest of the `authenticatedAttributes` structure. In this case the digest of the document data is stored as the value of a specific signed attribute, the "messageDigest" attribute. Thus, in this case you try to extract the wrong value to compare the document digest with.

For example in case of the example document you shared in your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54361974/1729265) there are `authenticatedAttributes`, so the inspiring blog led you astray.