# How to compute PDF signature hash?

Tags: bash, pdf, hash, sha256

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356538/how-to-extract-and-verify-pdf-signature-pkcs7-with-openssl) one, but a bit more specific. I am suspecting I am not computing the hash of my pdf properly.

I would like to compute the SHA256 hash of a signed PDF.

According to [PDF32000](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=482) I should:

1. Get the `\ByteRange` values
2. Concatenate the two chunks
3. Compute the SHA256

Here is what I did:

```
$ grep -aPo 'ByteRange\[\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*\]' dummy-signed.pdf
ByteRange[ 0 59718 72772 5058]

$ dd if=dummy-signed.pdf of=head.bin bs=1 skip=0 count=59718
59718 bytes (60 kB, 58 KiB) copied, 0.630196 s, 94.8 kB/s

$ dd if=dummy-signed.pdf of=tail.bin bs=1 skip=72772 count=5058
5058 bytes (5.1 kB, 4.9 KiB) copied, 0.064317 s, 78.6 kB/s

$ cat head.bin tail.bin > whole.bin

$ sha256sum whole.bin
04b69f55f12fa5cc7923f4307154f2702efde43b32e4a8d9dbb0507a56fcecd3  whole.bin
```

I checked that I am not including the `<` and `>` chars:

```
$ hexdump -C head.bin | tail -n3
0000e930  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 2f 43 6f  |             /Co|
0000e940  6e 74 65 6e 74 73                                 |ntents|
0000e946

$ hexdump -C tail.bin | head -n3
00000000  2f 46 69 6c 74 65 72 2f  41 64 6f 62 65 2e 50 50  |/Filter/Adobe.PP|
00000010  4b 4c 69 74 65 2f 4d 28  44 3a 32 30 31 39 30 31  |KLite/M(D:201901|
00000020  32 38 31 33 34 30 35 38  2b 30 31 27 30 30 27 29  |28134058+01'00')|
```

Unfortunately it seems my signature is wrong, but after decoding the `PKCS7` signature I double checked the hash is `sha256WithRSAEncryption`, so after verifying this digest I get another hash than the one I computed.

My `/SubFilter` is:

```
$ grep -aPo '/SubFilter.*?(?=>)' dummy-signed.pdf
/SubFilter/adbe.pkcs7.detached/Type/Sig
```

And my PDF version is:

```
$ grep -aPo '%PDF-\d.\d' dummy-signed.pdf
%PDF-1.6
```

So from PDF32000 with `adbe.pkcs7.detached` and PDF `1.6` the HASH should be SHA256 which is compatible with what I found in the PKCS7.

Just for the record, the hash I get from the signature is:

```
#!/bin/bash
PKCS7='out.pkcs7'

# Extract Digest (SHA256)
OFFSET=$(openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $PKCS7 | \
    perl -ne 'print $1 + $2 if /(\d+):d=\d\s+hl=(\d).*?256 prim.*HEX DUMP/m')
dd if=$PKCS7 of=signed-sha256.bin bs=1 skip=$OFFSET count=256

# Extract Public key 
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -inform der -in $PKCS7 | \
    tac | sed '/-----BEGIN/q' | tac > client.pem
openssl x509 -in client.pem -pubkey -noout > client.pub.pem

# Verify the signature
openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey client.pub.pem < signed-sha256.bin > verified.bin

# Get Hash and compare with the computed hash from the PDF
openssl asn1parse -inform der -in verified.bin | grep -Po '\[HEX DUMP\]:\K\w+$' | tr A-F a-f

$ ./verify-signature.sh
256+0 records in
256+0 records out
256 bytes copied, 0.029548 s, 8.7 kB/s
2a3f629f7bdce750321da7f219ec5759dc9ed14818acbd3cd0b6092d5371c03a
```

You can access the test PDF file `dummy-signed.pdf` from my [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nowox/94dd54e484df877e1232c18bd7b91c97/raw/d249f3757137e9b665e895c900f08b1156f1bc4f/dummy-signed.pdf.base64)

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nowox/94dd54e484df877e1232c18bd7b91c97/raw/d249f3757137e9b665e895c900f08b1156f1bc4f/dummy-signed.pdf.base64 | base64 --decode > dummy-signed.pdf
```

Comment: You completely ignore the **Subfilter** entry of your signature. Depending on the subfilter value the format of the signature container and the actually signed data do differ.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question for further analysis.

Comment: @mkl I have shared my PDF. Sorry for the base64. I don't know how to share pdf otherwise.

Comment: The easiest way to share PDFs (or arbitrary binaries except images to show inline) is to use a public file share (dropbox or google drive public share). But your base64 encoded gist worked, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short

**You try to extract the wrong hash value from the signature container.**

#### In detail

*I didn't recognize this earlier because I'm not really an openssl expert. Analyzing the example PDF, though, the cause of the confusion became clear.*

In a PKCS#7 / CMS signature container there usually are (at least) **two** hash values of interest:

- the hash value of the signed document data in the `messageDigest` signed attribute and
- the hash value of the signed attributes (in case of the old RSA signing scheme) in the encrypted signature bytes.

The `messageDigest` signed attribute in the signature container in your example document looks like this (appearances might differ if you asn1-dump in openssl but the value should be recognizable nonetheless):

```
5306   47: . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
    <06 09>
5308    9: . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER messageDigest (1 2 840 113549 1 9 4)
         : . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
    <31 22>
5319   34: . . . . . . . SET {
    <04 20>
5321   32: . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING    
         : . . . . . . . . . 04 B6 9F 55 F1 2F A5 CC    ...U./..
         : . . . . . . . . . 79 23 F4 30 71 54 F2 70    y#.0qT.p
         : . . . . . . . . . 2E FD E4 3B 32 E4 A8 D9    ...;2...
         : . . . . . . . . . DB B0 50 7A 56 FC EC D3                            
         : . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . }
```

As you can recognize, this attribute contains the hash value you calculated.

You on the other hand try to extract the signed hash value from the decrypted signature bytes which is **not** the hash of the document but instead the hash of the signed attributes!

Additionally something appears to go wrong in that extraction step, the value you should retrieve is

```
AB86B27177E388A1EE69A5C7479D74621E84473E0CAB5C647471B724FEFCE826
```

and not the

```
2a3f629f7bdce750321da7f219ec5759dc9ed14818acbd3cd0b6092d5371c03a
```

you got.