# Signed PDF content digest calculated during verification is different from decrypted digest from signature

Tags: java, pdf, hash, signature, verify

I am using properly signed PDF and standard libraries to check message digest. 
signerInformation.getContentDigest() return digest value different from decripted digestInfo.getDigest() value. In addition, signature verification fails on properly signed PDF file.

Went through all possible questions about digital signature.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.DigestInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationVerifier;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

public class PDFSignatureValidatorSample {

    public static void verifyPDF(byte[] doc) throws Exception {     
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(doc);
        List<PDSignature> signatures = document.getSignatureDictionaries();
        PDSignature sig = signatures.get(0);
        if (sig != null) {
            String subFilter = sig.getSubFilter();
            if (subFilter != null) {
                Collection<X509Certificate> certs = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
                switch (subFilter) {
                case "ETSI.CAdES.detached":
                case "adbe.pkcs7.detached":                 
                    byte[] signatureContent = sig.getContents(doc);
                    System.out.println("---------signatureContent length------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureContent.length);
                    String signatureContentB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureContent);
                    // System.out.println("---------signatureContent b64------------");
                    // System.out.println("signatureContentB64);                    
                    byte[] signedContent = sig.getSignedContent(doc);
                    String signedContentB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedContent);
                    System.out.println("---------signedContent length------------");
                    System.out.println(signedContent.length);
                    // System.out.println("---------signedContent b64------------");
                    // System.out.println(signedContentB64);

                    // Now we construct a PKCS #7 or CMS.
                    CMSProcessable cmsProcessableInputStream = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signedContent);
                    CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(cmsProcessableInputStream, signatureContent);
                    Store certificatesStore = cmsSignedData.getCertificates();
                    Collection<SignerInformation> signers = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos().getSigners();
                    SignerInformation signerInformation = signers.iterator().next();
                    Collection matches = certificatesStore.getMatches(signerInformation.getSID());
                    X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) matches.iterator().next();
                    certificateHolder.getSerialNumber();
                    X509Certificate certFromSignedData = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
                            .getCertificate(certificateHolder);
                    certs.add(certFromSignedData);

                    SignerInformationVerifier signerInformationVerifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder()
                            .build(certificateHolder);
                    boolean isValid = signerInformation.verify(signerInformationVerifier);

                    System.out.println("---------isValid - checked by signerInformation ------------");
                    System.out.println(isValid);
                    System.out.println("---------certSerialNumber dec------------");
                    System.out.println(certificateHolder.getSerialNumber());
                    System.out.println("---------certSerialNumber hex------------");
                    System.out.println(String.format("0x%08X", certificateHolder.getSerialNumber()));
                    System.out.println("---------getContentType------------");
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getContentType().toString());
                    System.out.println("---------contentDigest base64------------");
                    byte[] contentDigest = signerInformation.getContentDigest();
                    String contentDigestB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(contentDigest);
                    System.out.println(contentDigestB64);
                    System.out.println("---------contentDigest hex------------");
                    String contentDigestHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(contentDigest);
                    System.out.println(contentDigestHex);
                    System.out.println("---------digestAlgOID------------");
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getDigestAlgOID());
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getDigestAlgorithmID());
                    System.out.println("---------encryptionAlgOID------------");
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getEncryptionAlgOID());

                    byte[] signatureBytes = signerInformation.getSignature();
                    String signatureBytesB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (encrypted) base64------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureBytesB64);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (encrypted) hex------------");
                    String signatureBytesHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println(signatureBytesHex);


                    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
                    PublicKey publicKey = certFromSignedData.getPublicKey();
                    byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
                    String publicKeyBytesB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes);
                    String publicKeyHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(publicKeyBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------publicKey base64------------");
                    System.out.println(publicKeyBytesB64);
                    System.out.println("---------publicKey hex------------");
                    System.out.println(publicKeyHex);
                    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
                    byte[] cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(signatureBytes);
                    String cipherTextB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (decrypted) base64------------");
                    System.out.println(cipherTextB64);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (decrypted) hex------------");
                    String cipherTextHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText);
                    System.out.println(cipherTextHex);

                    byte[] digest = null;

                    ASN1InputStream ais = new ASN1InputStream(cipherText);
                    ASN1Primitive obj = ais.readObject();
                    DigestInfo digestInfo = new DigestInfo((ASN1Sequence) obj);
                    System.out.println("---------getAlgorithmId------------");
                    System.out.println(digestInfo.getAlgorithmId().getAlgorithm().getId());                 
                    System.out.println("---------getDigest hex------------");
                    digest = digestInfo.getDigest();                    
                    String digestHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);
                    System.out.println(digestHex);
                    ais.close();


                    final Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
                    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
                    signature.update(digest);
                    boolean signatureVerified = signature.verify(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------signature.verify------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureVerified);

                    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
                    Signature bcSignature = Signature.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
                    bcSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
                    bcSignature.update(digest);
                    boolean signatureVerifiedBC = bcSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------signature bc.verify------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureVerifiedBC);

                    if (digestHex != contentDigestHex) {
                        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");                       
                        System.out.println("---------VERIFICATION FAILED---------");
                        System.out.println("---------calculated digest------------");
                        System.out.println(contentDigestHex);
                        System.out.println("---------decrypted digest ------------");
                        System.out.println(digestHex);
                        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("VERIFICATION PASSED");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new IOException("Unknown certificate type " + subFilter);

                };
            };
        };
    };


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "c:/test.pdf";
        byte[] doc = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
        verifyPDF(doc);
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
---------signatureContent length------------
18944
---------signedContent length------------
91250
---------isValid - checked by signerInformation ------------
true
---------certSerialNumber dec------------
8811972559309533840
---------certSerialNumber hex------------
0x7A4A6A5AD8227290
---------getContentType------------
1.2.840.113549.1.7.1
---------contentDigest base64------------
hcDVAjmJolBuurj1d2/2vWgO1bajqj1M8gGsQTGa/7w=
---------contentDigest hex------------
85C0D5023989A2506EBAB8F5776FF6BD680ED5B6A3AA3D4CF201AC41319AFFBC
---------digestAlgOID------------
2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier@da3a9fbd
---------encryptionAlgOID------------
1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
---------getSignature (encrypted) base64------------
uV9h778EUQ0wl7O9vNd5bvuzaq/XEx0zHeSnGKWAQQGqPe1YkKByZ1Pexo4ZZ6MqrKx7Ofpvje2gMhls6SAqqs4U2bMdrrM7a3udLDWLjjCHNy90zne2KUz/737gpIbiV4kzWbxlh44oWYgwM1Zc73hwWfh+I7G/fw0H//U4fgjnxbkXIEYU/zBOqQX4xlsWSAvAs1LB1N2+ySCGU9XvT5Btj9/F+e6hH8yMoyOFB1GrChdyasToUNq+5yAQa28nIxCcURvPo20mDtACgccLCVX+joMlFT21SI7mXIiFsIdBzGMqenyi7atJV53Gtvmp+tIpxowsvWTbCEMofsYVHw==
---------getSignature (encrypted) hex------------
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
---------publicKey base64------------
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxR7C91bL7cfR6NFMUvDCTtg4Fp91AH89efm7+1u2NO/nJNAtKvlhItNz4GDv28Ffp5WvKRZlHe5ORbnFvbHOaAAFG43k/tIx23ePa63TdYo8LY5M1/Auw2qDt7UZPZ4vbyABF7wtuNySrYOEcK5pdyAcXjECYHfEQSAH7DItOxMtU9I+Scl7oVo5rFHWEWWxBj3sIW5hxTUAVI9kZufi53XO5jEsHwh+5olR0tsJvrEeUPFHanPiBLi3Y+rrRMimPEeqfHV8jY+rZouovWEoivxNyLb3aooihAS5x4tC1A9p92TeQHBu3RZNfoC9KBB5F0iyb/CAFw9k5Aype8vgDQIDAQAB
---------publicKey hex------------
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
---------getSignature (decrypted) base64------------
MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIOFF1ONvV7F2h9Cq5WOGXtM0CvzuwMyL2zahkGwcjebN
---------getSignature (decrypted) hex------------
3031300D060960864801650304020105000420E145D4E36F57B17687D0AAE563865ED3340AFCEEC0CC8BDB36A1906C1C8DE6CD
---------getAlgorithmId------------
2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
---------getDigest hex------------
E145D4E36F57B17687D0AAE563865ED3340AFCEEC0CC8BDB36A1906C1C8DE6CD
---------signature.verify------------
false
---------signature bc.verify------------
false
--------------------------------------
---------VERIFICATION FAILED---------
---------calculated digest------------
85C0D5023989A2506EBAB8F5776FF6BD680ED5B6A3AA3D4CF201AC41319AFFBC
---------decrypted digest ------------
E145D4E36F57B17687D0AAE563865ED3340AFCEEC0CC8BDB36A1906C1C8DE6CD
--------------------------------------
```

File was signed using DSS Demonstration WebApp
https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/sign-a-document

File can be validated DSS Demonstration WebApp
https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation

```
        <DigestMatcher type="MESSAGE_DIGEST">
            <DigestMethod>SHA256</DigestMethod>
            <DigestValue>hcDVAjmJolBuurj1d2/2vWgO1bajqj1M8gGsQTGa/7w=</DigestValue>
            <DataFound>true</DataFound>
            <DataIntact>true</DataIntact>
        </DigestMatcher>
```

DSS Demonstration WebApp calculates the same digest as presented code.

Digest from signature can be decrypted using openssl:

```
signature=uV9h778EUQ0wl7O9vNd5bvuzaq/XEx0zHeSnGKWAQQGqPe1YkKByZ1Pexo4ZZ6MqrKx7Ofpvje2gMhls6SAqqs4U2bMdrrM7a3udLDWLjjCHNy90zne2KUz/737gpIbiV4kzWbxlh44oWYgwM1Zc73hwWfh+I7G/fw0H//U4fgjnxbkXIEYU/zBOqQX4xlsWSAvAs1LB1N2+ySCGU9XvT5Btj9/F+e6hH8yMoyOFB1GrChdyasToUNq+5yAQa28nIxCcURvPo20mDtACgccLCVX+joMlFT21SI7mXIiFsIdBzGMqenyi7atJV53Gtvmp+tIpxowsvWTbCEMofsYVHw==
publicKey=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxR7C91bL7cfR6NFMUvDCTtg4Fp91AH89efm7+1u2NO/nJNAtKvlhItNz4GDv28Ffp5WvKRZlHe5ORbnFvbHOaAAFG43k/tIx23ePa63TdYo8LY5M1/Auw2qDt7UZPZ4vbyABF7wtuNySrYOEcK5pdyAcXjECYHfEQSAH7DItOxMtU9I+Scl7oVo5rFHWEWWxBj3sIW5hxTUAVI9kZufi53XO5jEsHwh+5olR0tsJvrEeUPFHanPiBLi3Y+rrRMimPEeqfHV8jY+rZouovWEoivxNyLb3aooihAS5x4tC1A9p92TeQHBu3RZNfoC9KBB5F0iyb/CAFw9k5Aype8vgDQIDAQAB

echo $signature | base64 --decode > signature.bin
echo -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- > publicKey.pem
echo $publicKey  >> publicKey.pem
echo -----END PUBLIC KEY----- >> publicKey.pem
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey publicKey.pem  -pubin -in signature.bin | 

openssl asn1parse -inform DER
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:E145D4E36F57B17687D0AAE563865ED3340AFCEEC0CC8BDB36A1906C1C8DE6CD
```

openssl also returns the same decrypted digest as presented code.

Test file is available here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UlOZOp-UYllK7Ra35dggccoWdhcb_Ntp

Message digest decrypted from signature (“real digest”) is definitely digest that must be used for comparison with calculated message digest. This value is in file; more precisely, encrypted in signature field and has to be decrypted with public key (extracted from certificate). This is a fact. 
According to the SignerInformation documentation getContentDigest() - return the content digest that was calculated during verification. Verification was successful, as signerInformation verify returned true. As stated, this value is calculated, not read from file (or some field in file), and indeed it has to be calculated. These two values should match. 
Those facts lead to the conclusion that both values are most likely equal but given hex or b64 representation differ. The question is how original binary of values is encoded and how are they decoded from binary to their representation or better the question is how to get “real digest” from pdf file using standard java libraries.

Comment: The [question yours is closed as a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361974/how-to-compute-pdf-signature-hash) is about determining the hash manually with openssl. Nonetheless both your code and the approach in that other question do the same mistake: You compare the hash of the signed document bytes with the wrong hash value in the signature container! In a non-trivial signature container there are (at least!) *two hash values of interest* and you picked the wrong one to compare with.

Comment: The question cannot be closed as a duplicate because it is not about determining the hash manually with openssl. It is question how determine the hash manually with java! openssl in problem description is used just to confirm that decrypted hash value is indeed the same given by java code and openssl.

Comment: As stated earlier “real digest” is for sure the one decrypted from signature if PDF is properly signed (we eliminate signature spoofing), and given test file is indeed properly signed (this can be verified with a bunch of commercial software available). So the question is how to calculate digest on signed PDF in java that will correspond to decrypted ie. “real digest”.  Most likely this is an encoding issue regarding the format how decrypted hash is written and how calculated hash is written and then represented for comparison.

Comment: Your original question text didn't contain an actual question at all, merely a final statement "both digest values should be equal". Why this statement is wrong, is explained in the answer to the duplicated answer. You apparently have not read the answers to the duplicated questions, otherwise you would not have written *'Message digest decrypted from signature (“real digest”) is definitely digest that must be used for comparison with calculated message digest.'* I'll try and re-open the question (I'm not sure I can) nonetheless to make way for an answer that explains PDF signing basics.

Comment: I went through all questions about digital signature. As described on Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature#/media/File:Digital_Signature_diagram.svg) for varification the hash (synonym for digest) is decrypted from signature using public key. As presented in problem statement this value is obtained by provided java code or openssl. Moreover, during the signing process it is possible to keep an eye on generated hash sent for a signing, and I can confirm it is the same hash that is decrypted from signature. Please re-open the question.

Comment: *"Please re-open the question"* - it has been re-opened nearly half an hour before you posted that. You probably have to press refresh F5. As an aside, that wikipedia image only applies if you use RSA signing, not for DSA or ECDSA signing.

Comment: Question is open. Thank you for very promt reaction. RSA signing is the case.

Answer (score 2):

###The backgrounds

The signed byte ranges of a PDF are signed using a CMS signature container (in case of the **Subfilter** values **adbe.pkcs7.detached** and **ETSI.CAdES.detached**).

The first step in the construction of a CMS signature container is

> For each signer, a message digest, or hash value, is computed on
> the content with a signer-specific message-digest algorithm.  If
> the signer is signing any information other than the content, the
> message digest of the content and the other information are
> digested with the signer's message digest algorithm (see Section
> 5.4), and the result becomes the "message digest."

*([RFC 5652 section 5 Signed-data Content Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5))*

and later

> The result of the message digest calculation process depends on
> whether the signedAttrs field is present.  When the field is absent,
> the result is just the message digest of the content as described
> above.  When the field is present, however, the result is the message
> digest of the complete DER encoding of the SignedAttrs value
> contained in the signedAttrs field.  Since the SignedAttrs value,
> when present, must contain the content-type and the message-digest
> attributes, those values are indirectly included in the result.

*([RFC 5652 section 5.4. Message Digest Calculation Process](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.4))*

You apparently believe to be in the case that only *the content* is signed, i.e. that *the signedAttrs field is absent*.

This believe is wrong, every CMS signature profile (as in CAdES/PAdES) to be taken seriously requires certain additional information to be signed.

Thus, the hash value you extract from the encrypted signature value is *not the hash of the signed PDF byte ranges but of the signed attributes* and the hash of the signed PDF byte ranges merely is the value of one of those attributes, the message-digest attribute

If you inspect an ASN.1 dump of that signature container (openssl also allows you to create an ASN.1 dump, try it!), you'll find the (implicitly 0-tagged) signed attributes starting at offset 1828:

```
1828  234: . . . . . [0] {
1831   24: . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1833    9: . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER contentType (1 2 840 113549 1 9 3)
         : . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
1844   11: . . . . . . . SET {
1846    9: . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER data (1 2 840 113549 1 7 1)
         : . . . . . . . . . (PKCS #7)
         : . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . }
1857   47: . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1859    9: . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER messageDigest (1 2 840 113549 1 9 4)
         : . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
1870   34: . . . . . . . SET {
1872   32: . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING    
         : . . . . . . . . . 85 C0 D5 02 39 89 A2 50    ....9..P
         : . . . . . . . . . 6E BA B8 F5 77 6F F6 BD    n...wo..
         : . . . . . . . . . 68 0E D5 B6 A3 AA 3D 4C    h.....=L
         : . . . . . . . . . F2 01 AC 41 31 9A FF BC                            
         : . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . }
1906  156: . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1909   11: . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . signingCertificateV2 (1 2 840 113549 1 9 16 2 47)
         : . . . . . . . . (S/MIME Authenticated Attributes)
1922  140: . . . . . . . SET {
1925  137: . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1928  134: . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1931  131: . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1934   32: . . . . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING    
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . 7E 0A 99 20 3C E5 79 10    ~.. <.y.
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . B7 22 59 58 A1 7F A3 3B    ."YX...;
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . C4 BC 78 14 BC C1 B6 A1    ..x.....
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . FF A6 AE 9E 0A FD 8D A6                            
1968   95: . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1970   83: . . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1972   81: . . . . . . . . . . . . . [4] {
1974   79: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1976   11: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SET {
1978    9: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1980    3: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . countryName (2 5 4 6)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (X.520 DN component)
1985    2: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . PrintableString 'HR'
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
1989   19: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SET {
1991   17: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1993    3: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . organizationName (2 5 4 10)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (X.520 DN component)
1998   10: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . UTF8String 'AKD d.o.o.'
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
2010   26: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SET {
2012   24: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
2014    3: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER '2 5 4 97'
2019   17: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . UTF8String 'VATHR-58843087891'
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
2038   15: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SET {
2040   13: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
2042    3: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . commonName (2 5 4 3)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (X.520 DN component)
2047    6: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . UTF8String 'HRIDCA'
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . }
2055    8: . . . . . . . . . . . . INTEGER 7A 4A 6A 5A D8 22 72 90                            
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . }
```

and the second entry therein is the hash value you were looking for:

```
1857   47: . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
1859    9: . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER messageDigest (1 2 840 113549 1 9 4)
         : . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
1870   34: . . . . . . . SET {
1872   32: . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING    
         : . . . . . . . . . 85 C0 D5 02 39 89 A2 50    ....9..P
         : . . . . . . . . . 6E BA B8 F5 77 6F F6 BD    n...wo..
         : . . . . . . . . . 68 0E D5 B6 A3 AA 3D 4C    h.....=L
         : . . . . . . . . . F2 01 AC 41 31 9A FF BC                            
         : . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . }
```

which is identical to the value you calculated

```
---------contentDigest base64------------
hcDVAjmJolBuurj1d2/2vWgO1bajqj1M8gGsQTGa/7w=
---------contentDigest hex------------
85C0D5023989A2506EBAB8F5776FF6BD680ED5B6A3AA3D4CF201AC41319AFFBC
```

###Extracting the messageDigest value with PDFBox and BouncyCastle

To extract the messageDigest value you can proceed as follows:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(THE_PDF);
List<PDSignature> signatures = document.getSignatureDictionaries();
PDSignature sig = signatures.get(0);
byte[] cmsBytes = sig.getContents(bytes);
CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(cmsBytes);
SignerInformation signerInformation = cms.getSignerInfos().iterator().next();
Attribute attribute = signerInformation.getSignedAttributes().get(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_messageDigest);
ASN1Encodable value = attribute.getAttributeValues()[0];
System.out.printf("MessageDigest attribute value: %s\n", value);
```

*([CalculateDigest](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/sign/CalculateDigest.java#L224) test `testExtractMessageDigestAttributeForUser2893427`)*

The output:

```
MessageDigest attribute value: #85c0d5023989a2506ebab8f5776ff6bd680ed5b6a3aa3d4cf201ac41319affbc
```

###An aside

You referred to a Wiki [diagram showing how a digital signature is applied and then verified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature#/media/File:Digital_Signature_diagram.svg). It can only be used to get the general idea, not to understand all details of specific signature profiles like CAdES/PAdES signature containers.

Furthermore, it isn't representative for all signing algorithms either. only for some, like RSA signing, you can actually *extract* the hash from the signature bytes value after decrypting; for others, like DSA and ECDSA, you can only check a given hash value against the signature bytes.

Comment: That is right. Thank you for very verbose explanation. That is right. Thank you for very verbose explanation.  Good result is achieved with:
` byte[] encodedSignedAttributes = signerInformation.getEncodedSignedAttributes();` and calculating the hash. I will update source to share it with others. Code for extracting value from ASN1 would be also usefull. Great!

Answer (score 2):

```
package hr.ccr.validator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.DigestInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationVerifier;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

public class PDFSignatureValidatorSample {

    public static void verifyPDF(byte[] doc) throws Exception {     
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(doc);
        List<PDSignature> signatures = document.getSignatureDictionaries();
        PDSignature sig = signatures.get(0);
        if (sig != null) {
            String subFilter = sig.getSubFilter();
            if (subFilter != null) {
                Collection<X509Certificate> certs = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
                switch (subFilter) {
                case "ETSI.CAdES.detached":
                case "adbe.pkcs7.detached":                 
                    byte[] signatureContent = sig.getContents(doc);
                    System.out.println("---------signatureContent length------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureContent.length);
                    String signatureContentB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureContent);
                    // System.out.println("---------signatureContent b64------------");
                    // System.out.println("signatureContentB64);                    
                    byte[] signedContent = sig.getSignedContent(doc);
                    String signedContentB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedContent);
                    System.out.println("---------signedContent length------------");
                    System.out.println(signedContent.length);
                    // System.out.println("---------signedContent b64------------");
                    // System.out.println(signedContentB64);

                    // Now we construct a PKCS #7 or CMS.
                    CMSProcessable cmsProcessableInputStream = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signedContent);
                    CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(cmsProcessableInputStream, signatureContent);
                    Store certificatesStore = cmsSignedData.getCertificates();

                    Collection<SignerInformation> signers = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos().getSigners();
                    SignerInformation signerInformation = signers.iterator().next();
                    Collection matches = certificatesStore.getMatches(signerInformation.getSID());
                    X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) matches.iterator().next();
                    certificateHolder.getSerialNumber();
                    X509Certificate certFromSignedData = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
                            .getCertificate(certificateHolder);
                    certs.add(certFromSignedData);

                    SignerInformationVerifier signerInformationVerifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder()
                            .build(certificateHolder);
                    boolean isValid = signerInformation.verify(signerInformationVerifier);

                    byte[] encodedSignedAttributes = signerInformation.getEncodedSignedAttributes();
                    String encodedSignedAttributesB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedSignedAttributes);
                    System.out.println("---------encodedSignedAttributesB64------------");
                    System.out.println(encodedSignedAttributesB64);
                    MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                    byte[] derSignedAttributesHash = sha256.digest(encodedSignedAttributes);
                    String derSignedAttributesHashB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(derSignedAttributesHash);
                    String derSignedAttributesHashHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(derSignedAttributesHash);
                    System.out.println("---------derSignedAttributesHashB64------------");
                    System.out.println(derSignedAttributesHashB64);
                    System.out.println("---------derSignedAttributesHashHex------------");
                    System.out.println(derSignedAttributesHashHex);                 

                    System.out.println("---------isValid - checked by signerInformation ------------");
                    System.out.println(isValid);
                    System.out.println("---------certSerialNumber dec------------");
                    System.out.println(certificateHolder.getSerialNumber());
                    System.out.println("---------certSerialNumber hex------------");
                    System.out.println(String.format("0x%08X", certificateHolder.getSerialNumber()));
                    System.out.println("---------getContentType------------");
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getContentType().toString());
                    System.out.println("---------contentDigest base64------------");
                    byte[] contentDigest = signerInformation.getContentDigest();
                    String contentDigestB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(contentDigest);
                    System.out.println(contentDigestB64);
                    System.out.println("---------contentDigest hex------------");
                    String contentDigestHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(contentDigest);
                    System.out.println(contentDigestHex);
                    System.out.println("---------digestAlgOID------------");
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getDigestAlgOID());
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getDigestAlgorithmID());
                    System.out.println("---------encryptionAlgOID------------");
                    System.out.println(signerInformation.getEncryptionAlgOID());

                    byte[] signatureBytes = signerInformation.getSignature();
                    String signatureBytesB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (encrypted) base64------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureBytesB64);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (encrypted) hex------------");
                    String signatureBytesHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println(signatureBytesHex);


                    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
                    PublicKey publicKey = certFromSignedData.getPublicKey();
                    byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
                    String publicKeyBytesB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes);
                    String publicKeyHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(publicKeyBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------publicKey base64------------");
                    System.out.println(publicKeyBytesB64);
                    System.out.println("---------publicKey hex------------");
                    System.out.println(publicKeyHex);
                    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
                    byte[] cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(signatureBytes);
                    String cipherTextB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (decrypted) base64------------");
                    System.out.println(cipherTextB64);
                    System.out.println("---------getSignature (decrypted) hex------------");
                    String cipherTextHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText);
                    System.out.println(cipherTextHex);

                    byte[] digest = null;

                    ASN1InputStream ais = new ASN1InputStream(cipherText);
                    ASN1Primitive obj = ais.readObject();
                    DigestInfo digestInfo = new DigestInfo((ASN1Sequence) obj);
                    System.out.println("---------getAlgorithmId------------");
                    System.out.println(digestInfo.getAlgorithmId().getAlgorithm().getId());                 
                    System.out.println("---------getDigest hex------------");
                    digest = digestInfo.getDigest();                    
                    String digestHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);
                    System.out.println(digestHex);
                    ais.close();


                    final Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
                    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
                    signature.update(encodedSignedAttributes);
                    boolean signatureVerified = signature.verify(signatureBytes);
                    System.out.println("---------signature.verify------------");
                    System.out.println(signatureVerified);

                    if (!digestHex.equalsIgnoreCase(derSignedAttributesHashHex)) {
                        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");                       
                        System.out.println("---------VERIFICATION FAILED---------");
                        System.out.println("---------calculated digest------------");
                        System.out.println(derSignedAttributesHashHex);
                        System.out.println("---------decrypted digest ------------");
                        System.out.println(digestHex);
                        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    }
                    else System.out.println("VERIFICATION PASSED");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IOException("Unknown certificate type " + subFilter);

                };
            };
        };



    };


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "c:/test.pdf";
        byte[] doc = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
        verifyPDF(doc);
    }

}
```